# How to load steps dynamically using Angular material stepper

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

I want to load  steps dynamically Like I have Offering component under that there are two steps label

1. Offering detail(it should load offering detail component)
2. Add User(it should display Add user component)

so stepper should display 2 steps only.

again I have `Datasourceaccess` component and under that 3 steps are there, so I want to build reusable stepper component which can be used by any components and should display steps according to components.

below stack blitz link, showcasing the above problem

**StackBlitz :** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4xg2no

Fyi, here I am working on `sharedwizard.component` and `sharedWizard.componet.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `[selectedIndex]="stepIndex"`, and using the component's controller to update the `stepIndex` as you expected

Comment: but how to pass different array value in steeper for loop like offering, datasource , datasourceaccess?

Comment: if I will use index and later if some one change the order of label then how it will work what approach should I follow.

Comment: How to load dynamically stepper

Comment: no, it is not that complicated. You just need to update the this.stepIndex whenever you want to update the index

Comment: stepIndex is just a number

Comment: Thanks Now I am able to do this